# How to compare two strings and replacing different bit with - in another string

Tags: vb.net, string, comparison

for example i have two strings 0000 and 0001 then

```
         0000
         0001
         ----
result=  000-  here difference is indicated by - sign
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare each character in the string:

```
Dim s1 = "0000"
Dim s2 = "0001"

Dim result = ""

If s1.Length = s2.Length Then

    For a = 0 To s1.Length - 1

        If s1(a) <> s2(a) Then
            result &= "-"
        Else
            result &= s1(a)
        End If

    Next

End If
```

Result = 000-